# What is the greatest and least possible value of $f(2)$ if $f(0)=3$ and $2 \le f'\left( x \right) \le 4$ for all $x\in[-5,5]$?

Tags: calculus

The information that is given is,

> $f(0)=3$ and $2 \le f'\left( x \right) \le 4$ for all $x$ in the interval $[-5,5]$.

Thinking Process:

Since $f'(x)$ is positive in the given interval, therefore, it is increasing in the interval. So the value of $f(2)>f(0)>3$, it cannot be 3 as its least value as $f'(x)$ never assumes value $=0$. 
The least value of $f(2)$ will be corresponding to $f'(2)=2$ and greatest value for $f'(2)=4$. The value of $f(x)$ can not increase without bound as well in the given interval as value if $f'(x)$ toggles between $2$ and $4$. How do I approach the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Use Mean value theorem.

You get $2 \le \frac {f(2)-f(0)}{2-0} \le 4$. Now put the value of $f(0)=3$.

Comment: How do I take this information into account that $f(x)$ is increasing in the interval $[-5,5]$ with the information that $f'(x)$ is never zero in the given interval. If I apply mean value theorem, I assumed that $f(x)$ is straight line between $[-5,0]$. Right?

Comment: You just have to check whether the given information in the problem fits within the hypothesis of the mean value theorem. So check : 1)$f$ is continuous on $[-5,5]$, 2)$f$ is differentiable on $[-5,5]$. So $f$ is also continuous and differentiable on $[0,2]$ right? Then just apply the mean value theorem considering the interval $[0,2]$. I did not assume anywhere that $f(x)$ is a straight line. Why put extra assumptions? Also regarding your approach that $f(x)$ is increasing and $f'(x) \neq 0$, I am also thinking about it. :)

Comment: Strictly speaking, you need Mathmore's and Farrukh Ataev's answer combined: Mathmore derives a lower bound for the least and an upper bound for the greatest possible value, whereas Farrukh Ataev shows that these bounds are actually achieved.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum and maximum functions satisfying the given conditions are $f(x)=2x+3$ and $f(x)=4x+3$, respectively. Hence: $7\le f(2) \le 11$.